# How to Invite Facebook Users to a Unity Game for Android

Tags: unity, android, multiplayer, facebook, plugin

I am currently using the following code to let the player invite other players to my multiplayer game:

```
FB.AppRequest("Test Message", callback: this.HandleResult);
```

and

```
FB.AppRequest("Test Message", null, null, null, null, null, null, callback: this.HandleResult);
```

When tested on an Android phone, it only brought up a Facebook dialog box for the player to choose his/her friends. Clicking "Send" would close the dialog box, but no message whatsover would be received on the target person's Facebook.

I used to do:

```
FB.Mobile.AppInvite(new Uri("xxxx"), callback: this.HandleResult);
```

but I understand this has been obsolete, invoking only a black blank screen.

I applied for a 'user_friends' Facebook permission but was told it was not required.

Both 'Single Sign On' and 'Deep Linking' have been enabled on the Basic Settings page at Facebook Developer.

What else should I try?

I tried to print out the result of the callback function which looks like this:

```
public void HandleResult(IResult result){
    string r = "";
    if (result == null) return;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error)) r += "Error Response: " + result.Error + "\n";
    else if (result.Cancelled) r +=  "Cancelled Response: " + result.RawResult + "\n";
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.RawResult)) r += "Success Response:" + result.RawResult + "\n";
    else r+= "Empty Response\n";
    r+=result.ToString();
    GameObject.Find("FBText").GetComponent<Text>().text = r;
}
```

and obtained the following:

```
Success Response: {"request":"415323562654670","callback_id":"2","to":"3XXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
Facebook.Unity.AppRequestResult
AppRequestResult:
   Error: null
   RawResult:{"request":"415323562654670","callback_id":"2","to":"3XXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
   Cancelled: False
AppRequestResult:
   RequestID: 415323562654670
   To: 3XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The request seemed to be successful. However, no invitation was received at the target account.

I am using the latest Facebook SDK -- version 7.15.1.

Comment: First of all, I recommend using version 7.13. Version 7.15 is broken as hell, there's an issue with in-app purchases callbacks which causes crashes.

Regarding the problem, I remember, that when I published my first app, after 1 or two weeks the FB login stopped working, with a message that one of the tokens is the debug token. I don't really remember which token was that, but when googled, I found it and replaced it.

I'll try to look at that later and post it here.

Comment: Did you ever managed to resolve this? I am running into exactly same issue right now. Though my app is not yet published, so maybe that could be an issue?

Comment: I don't think publishing is the issue as Facebook is not directly linked to Google Play Store. They made some changes to their APIs. I gave up trying and just removed that functionality in the end.